# Can I provide AWS credentials via mounted directory to local Docker container built by sbt-native-packager

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sbt-native-packager

We have some docker images we build with sbt-native-packager that need to interact with AWS services. When running them outside of AWS, we need to explicitly provide credentials.

I know we can explicitly pass environment variables containing the AWS credentials. Doing this complicates keeping our credentials secret. One option is to provide them via the command line, typically storing them into our shell history (yes I know this can be avoided by adding a space to the start of the command, but that is easy to forget) and putting them at higher risk of accidental copy/paste sharing. Alternatively, we can provide them via an env-file. But this exposes us to possibly checking them into version control or pushing them to another server unintentionally.

We've found that the ideal practice is to mount our local `~/.aws/` directory into the running user's home directory for the docker container. However, our attempts at getting this to work with the sbt-native-packager images have been unsuccessful.

One unique detail for sbt-native-packager images (compared to our others) is they are build using docker's ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD to start the application. I don't know if this has bearing on the problem.

So the question: Is it possible to provide AWS credentials to a docker container created by sbt-native-packager by mounting the AWS credentials folder via command line parameters at startup?

Answer (score 4):

The problem I was running into was related to permissions. The `.aws` files have very restricted access on my machine, and the default user within the sbt-native-packager image is `daemon`. This user does not have access to read my files when mounted into the container.

I am able to obtain the behavior I desire by adding the following flags to my docker run command: `-v ~/.aws/:/root/.aws/ --user=root`

I was able to discover this by using the `--entrypoint=ash` flag when running to look at the `HOME` environment variable (location to mount the `/.aws/` folder) and attempting to `cat` the contents of mounted folder.

Now I just need to understand what security vulnerabilities I'm opening myself up to by running docker containers in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why mounting `~/.aws` would be a problem - typically it could be related to read permissions on that directory and the different UID between the host system and the container.

That said, I can suggest a couple of workarounds:

1. Use an environment variable file instead of explicitly specifying them in the command line. In `docuer run`, you can do this by specifying `--env-file`. To me this sounds like the most simple approach.
2. Mount a different credentials file and provide the `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable to specify it's location.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the AWS_CONFIG_FILE. When I tried using that and things still didn't work, I found how get into the running container to look at what is going on.  Unfortunately, no messages were logged when the SDK couldn't access these files.